# math on working out this integral

Tags: integration

Please help me understand the following.
How do you get from here:

cos3θ=1/4(cos3θ+3cosθ).

Replacing θ by 2x, we have,

cos3(2x)=1/4(cos(6x)+3cos(2x)).

∴∫cos3(2x)dx=∫{1/4(cos(6x)+3cos(2x))}dx,

to here:

=1/4∫cos(6x)dx+3/4∫cos(2x)dx

Where does the 3/4 come from? Shouldn't it just be a 3 what you take out from the integral and move to he left?

Thank you.

Comment: Your initial formula is  for $\cos^3\theta$, not $\cos 3\theta$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to distribute the $\frac{1}{4}$: $\frac{1}{4}(\cos 6x + 3 \cos 2x) = \frac{1}{4} \cos 6x + \frac{3}{4} \cos 2x$.

Comment: Right. Thank you!